# How do you describe someone who is into incest?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

pedophile - one who is into pre-pubescent children

_____phile - one who is into incest?

Is there a single word that fits into "He's a ______" to describe someone who is into incest?

A hyphenated word is fine.

Comment: Incestiferous, i.e. "containing incest" (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-iferous) would work with a slightly modified sentence structure. Sadly, the word is not officially recognized, so you can expect trouble should you use it.

Comment: I seem to remember this was addressed in South Park: The Movie (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48XreePDi8k)...

Comment: british. sorry that's a joke. you can find the answer readily on-line, unless you want some more vulgar / slang phrases?

Comment: There are plenty of vulgar phrases but they tend to relate to specific relationships (e.g. sons who have sex with their mother). There are a lot of different types of incest, from relationships between first cousins, which may or may not be considered incest depending on culture, to the Oedipal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Incestuous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incestuous)  (adj): (the noun is *incestuousnesses*)

> - adj.
>     Of, involving, or suggestive of incest.
> - having committed incest.

- Someone who *commits incest* is the more common way to refer to an incestuous person.

A less common term is *[incestophile](http://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incest)* according to Wikipedia:

> - A person who engages in incest is called an incestophile.